# Android recyclerview: more efficient notifydatasetchanged or notifydatarangeremoved then notifydatarangeinserted?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview whose number of elements changes all the time. Sometimes it might have 5 items, sometimes 7, sometimes 70. What is the more efficient way of changing out the entire dataset:

1) calling clear(), adding the new dataset then calling notifydatasetchanged?

2) calling clear(), then calling notifyitemrangeremoved, then adding the new dataset and calling notifyItemRangeInserted?

```
public void swapData(ArrayList<dataType>() newdata) {
 int oldSize = recyclerlist.size();
        recyclerlist.clear();

        if (oldSize > 0) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, oldSize);
        } ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way involves a few steps, but only works if your items have proper ids.

1. Override `getItemId(int position)` and return the item's id.
2. In your RecyclerAdapter's contructor, add this line:

   ```
   setHadStableIds(true);
   ```
3. Just use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your swapData method after you've switched the lists.